# How to define from where the script loads files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I use a part of my script to load data from registered files `.npz`.

`Here is the code`:

```
Tk().withdraw() # Here starts the first loading phase, where I pick the file I want from a window
filename = askopenfilename()
with load(filename) as data:
    # file loading logic here
    pass

ext = '.npz'
for i in range(1, NF): # Here starts the second part, which loads one by one from the folder where the script is.
    filename = str(i)  + ext
    with load(filename) as data:
        XYsliceTemp = data['XYslice']
```

So what is my question? Right now, when I am at the second phase described, it loads one by one files from the folder where the script is. 
I would like to code it in a way that I can choose (with an opening window, or by writing something in the code with a full address) where it will goes to load the files (all the files are always in the same folder)

This is the background: I am going to stock my data on a HDD which are not meant to work on, so I cant install python on it and run it from there.
So I would like to tell to my script on my computer: go get those files on the HDD at this exact location.

Actually, the first phase loads the file 0, and then the second one loads from the 1 to the N one. So if I could say: Where I chose to load the 0, go there to find the N others, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *os.path.split()* and *os.path.join()* methods:

```
import os

filename = askopenfilename()
directory = os.path.split(filename)[0]

ext = 'npz'

for i in range(1, NF):
    filename = os.path.join(directory, '%s.%s' % (i, ext))
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you !  It seems convenient and easy.
I will try this asap.